# I want to find Java open source projects with many unit testcases

Tags: java, unit-testing

We are doing some research on automatic debugging for java programs. We want to find some Java open source projects with large set of unit testcases (Junit).

Anyone has some recommendations?

Thank you so much.

Zhongxian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android CTS](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html) has more than 10000 tests.

Answer (score 3):

if you go here you can use regex as your search query to find lots of projects with lots of unit tests or any mix you desire:  http://google.com/codesearch

Answer (score 2):

Lucene (@http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/HowToContribute)

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Framework](http://www.springframework.org).